# Need to find an attribute value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pit>
    <ROW ExecutionID="1366617710" Date="2011-11-09 00:04:04.303" AssertionName="Check for critical conditions" />
    <ROW ExecutionID="1366619608" Date="2011-11-09 00:04:16.893" AssertionName="Check for critical conditions" />
</Pit>
```

I am trying to retrieve the date value based on a certain executionID.

I tried using the below query, but I reach an "exception". It's fairly simple but dunno why it fails.

The exception message is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
public static string GetRowError(XDocument xmlDoc, string executionID)
{
    string resultType = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        resultType = (from testResult in xmlDoc.Elements("Pit")
            where
            testResult != null  && 
            testResult.Attribute("ExecutionID").Value.Equals(executionID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == true
            select testResult.Attribute("Date").Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resultType = ex.ToString();
    }

    return resultType;
}
```

Comment: Posting the exception would be nice, in addition doesn't equals return a bool? Why do you == true in the end?

Comment: I recieve an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I use "== true" to check if the executionID is equal to the execution ID from the parameter

Comment: Check if `xmlDoc` is null, either by debugging or adding `if (xmlDoc == null) return "document null";`

Comment: xmldoc is not null...it does contain the "loaded" xml file. I did a quickwatch to check this.

Comment: @SourabhTewari You don't have to compare .Equals(..) with true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlDoc.Elements("Pit")
```

will return the `<Pit>` elements, the rest off your logic assumes they are `<ROW>` elements.

Either use `xmlDoc.Elements("Pit").Elements()` or directly select `xmlDoc.Descendants("ROW")`.

Your error is caused by:

```
var attr = xmlDoc.Elements("Pit").Attribute("ExecutionID");  // attr = null
var id = attr.Value;  // error, attr == null
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Henk Holterman answer - just an improvement :

```
    var resultType = (from testResult in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("ROW")
                  where testResult.Attribute("ExecutionID") != null && testResult.Attribute("ExecutionID").Value.Equals(executionID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                  select testResult.Attribute("Date").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would write my query like this because it accounts for an element without the executionID and also the == true is not needed. Equals returns bool so why are you comparing it with true? No reason at all.